# StatusCode: 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am having this 500 Internal Server Error when sending a POST resquest.

**Code:**

```
private async void btnRegister_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Users user = new Users()
            {
                mem_account_no = entId.Text,
                mem_acc_username = entUsername.Text,
                mem_acc_password = entPassword.Text
            };
            //signup.Text = user.mem_account_no;

            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user);

            var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

             var result = await client.PostAsync("http://ropenrom24-001-site1.etempurl.com/potangina/final/Restserver/index.php/users/insert", content);

            if (result.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Created)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Success", "Success" , "OK");
            }
            else
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Failed", "" + result, "OK");
            }
        }
```

I think the problem here is the Serialiation of object (user) to json, because I see this `Content-Type: txt/html;` when displaying the `var result`, while on the Windows form it shows `Content-Type: application/json;` . btw I have the same code with my Anrdoid and Windows form.

Comment: I don't intend to be condescending here, but 500 Internal Server Error means that the server (ropenrom24-001-site1) encountered an error processing your request. The _response_ content type isn't related to the content you are posting to the service in any way, shape, or form. The reason you're getting `text/html` is probably because the server is erroring, and returning a textual message, perhaps with error details. You should inspect the response to see if it provides more information, or contact the service provider to ask them why you're getting an error.

Comment: I'm voting to close the question as this isn't something we can help you with.

Comment: thanks sir but why does it works on my windows form? and when I pass the var json to a label its empty

Comment: No idea. The request code (the code that you've posted) looks generally correct. I say "generally" to mean that you do the right things to post JSON to an API that accepts JSON. If it works from Windows but not on Android, then you should compare your requests to find out how they differ.

Comment: Responding to your comment edit: What do you mean "empty"? Do you mean that all the properties are empty, or that it's just an empty string (`""`). If all the properties are empty, chances are your problem lies with `ent****.Text`. If you can, step through with the debugger and inspect everything.

Comment: Microsoft has some [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/debugging/) on how to debug Xamarin code (in case you're new to debugging).

Comment: try this might help you      
`var nvc = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
nvc.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("mem_account_no ", entId.Text));   
var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post,"api/Vendor/AccountEnquiry"){ Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(nvc) };   var res = await client.SendAsync(req); `

Comment: yes its empty. when I pass the string of the json to a label it show this { }